# Preventing grid from spreading and occupying all of its parent control's space

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, styles, size

I've got the following styling that produces a desired look.

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultStackPanelStyle" TargetType="StackPanel">
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="RowDefinition">
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="DefaultColumnStyle" TargetType="ColumnDefinition">
  <Setter Property="Width" Value="120"></Setter>
</Style>
```

I'd expect that, since the panels (that are placed in the cells of the grid) are set to a fix size, it'd spread to the containing rows and columns. I've tried both *Auto* and *** as width/height of the columns/rows but that led the grid to spread all over the place.

When I looked at the designer, the stack panel is actually marked to the the size I set. It's the padding of the cells that gets a lot of emptiness in it.

What did I forgot to consider?

Comment: Sounds like an easy fix, but having trouble visualizing your issue between the stackpanel and the grid's column/row definitions. Might have to share a little more of a layout to reproduce the issue or maybe a quick screen shot or something to help visualize what you get vs what you want.

Comment: I might have found the issue. I think so, at least. I had my grid placed on a tag item and it simply wanted to occupy all of the parent component. When I added a stack panel between the tab item and the grid, the behavior became consistent with the intention. However, I wonder if there's a general way to make the content (which is a grid in this case) not to occupy all the contents of the parent (tab item here) without adding any other control in between.

Comment: Yea, there's always a way, that's one thing I really dig about xaml. If you hit a bump come on back and we'll get you sorted, you shouldn't need controls in between or anything, if you give a quick/dirty visualization of what you want, chances are I can show you how easier than you might think.